# store ffmpeg command output to aws s3

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I run below command that is working perfectly in local file sysytem.

**Command:**

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.config('medialibrary.s3.domain').'/listing_video/intro.mp4'.' -vf "drawtext=fontfile=' . storage_path('assets/video/FutuMd.ttf') . ': text=' . $request->get('intro_text') . ': x=300: y=450: fontsize=65: fontcolor=white: enable=\'between(t,2,5)\'" introfinal.mp4');
```

but i have to store file direct to s3 so i changed my command that is store file to s3 but filesize is 0B.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.config('medialibrary.s3.domain').'/listing_video/intro.mp4'.' -vf "drawtext=fontfile=' . storage_path('assets/video/FutuMd.ttf') . ': text=' . $request->get('intro_text') . ': x=300: y=450: fontsize=65: fontcolor=white: enable=\'between(t,2,5)\'" '.Storage::put('introfinal.mp4', '').'');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Storage::put('introfinal.mp4', '')` expects the file contents between the `''`, it does not pipe in content from the exec result, in fact, before the command is run it tries to store it, and returns a boolean that gets put into the string

Comment: @SergeyKovalev i added aws credential in my .env file and also in filesystems.php config file in laravel

Answer (score 0):

This example is not perfect, but will point you in the right direction:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.config('medialibrary.s3.domain').'/listing_video/intro.mp4'.' -vf "drawtext=fontfile=' . storage_path('assets/video/FutuMd.ttf') . ': text=' . $request->get('intro_text') . ': x=300: y=450: fontsize=65: fontcolor=white: enable=\'between(t,2,5)\'" introfinal.mp4');

$contents = file_get_contents('introfinal.mp4');

$success = Storage::put('introfinal.mp4', $contents);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but i want direct save to s3.

Comment: [then this might help you further](https://loige.co/aws-command-line-s3-content-from-stdin-or-to-stdout/)